# Find the youngest customer with AT LEAST 1 purchase order

Tags: mysql, sql, analytical

I need to write a query to find the youngest customer who bought atleast 1 product

Here is the data:
CUSTOMER:

[image]

ORDER_DETAIL:

[image]

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMERID, c.age, c.name
from (
SELECT CUSTOMERID, COUNT(ORDERID) as "totalOrder"
FROM FACEBOOK_ORDER_DETAIL
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID 
HAVING COUNT(ORDERID) >=1) AS tbl
LEFT JOIN FACEBOOK_CUSTOMER c on c.CUSTOMERID = tbl.CUSTOMERID
order by c.age ;
```

However, above query gives me [image]

But I need the list of customers with the minimum age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really only want a single youngest customer, even should there be a tie, then use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMERID, c.age, c.name
FROM CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN FACEBOOK_ORDER_DETAIL o
    ON c.CUSTOMERID = c.CUSTOMERID
ORDER BY
    c.age
LIMIT 1;
```

This should work because if a customer joins to the order details table, it implies that he had at least one order.

If instead you want to find *all* youngest customers, including all ties, then a nice way to handle this uses the `RANK` analytic function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMERID, age, name
FROM
(
    SELECT c.CUSTOMERID, c.age, c.name, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c.age) rnk
    FROM CUSTOMER c
    INNER JOIN FACEBOOK_ORDER_DETAIL o
        ON c.CUSTOMERID = o.CUSTOMERID
) t
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

### Demo

For earlier versions of MySQL, we can use a subquery as a workaround for not having `RANK`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CUSTOMERID, c.age, c.name
FROM CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN FACEBOOK_ORDER_DETAIL o
    ON c.CUSTOMERID = c.CUSTOMERID
WHERE c.age = (SELECT MIN(t1.age)
               FROM CUSTOMER t1
               INNER JOIN FACEBOOK_ORDER_DETAIL t2
                   ON t1.CUSTOMERID = t2.CUSTOMERID);
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I do need all the potential customers with the youngest age criteria.

Comment: @gabs I gave you a couple of options for how to do that, depending on your MySQL version.

Comment: Second query with rank() is not working for me, its giving me ALL the customers including the ones without any purchase order. and the third query is giving me multiple records per order for the 3 customers satisfying min age criteria.

Comment: Not sure where the `RANK` query went wrong, but for the third query using `SELECT DISTINCT` should fix the problem you pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, `distinct` did work!! However, is there any way I can avoid self join for better scalability if the table is huge ?

Comment: @gabs I have imported your sample data, and my second and third query do appear to be working.  If it still doesn't "work" for you, then maybe your data has a problem, or perhaps you copied over my answer incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You only want columns from `customers`, so I would phrase this as:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             rank() over (order by age) as seqnum
      from customers c
      where exists (select 1
                    from facebook_order_detail fod
                    where fod.customerid = c.customerid
                   )
    ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

In particular, this requires no duplicate elimination or aggregation, so it should be faster.  And it can use an index on `face_book_details(customerid)` and also perhaps on `customers(age, customerid)`.

Comment: this would work fine with the given sample data. However, if a table is huge, wouldn't using `Exists` in the query would hamper the query performance ?

Comment: @gabs . . . Much less so than the alternatives.  Plus, with the right indexing, this is probably the fastest way to write the logic.